# Remote Service Administration

Tags: c#, service, impersonation

I am trying adminstrate a service on a different machine using a ServiceController.

```
        var sc = new ServiceController(serviceName, machine);
        Console.WriteLine(sc.Status);
```

As I need to use different credentials, I perform an impersonation using:

```
        var tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, password,
                                     LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
                                     LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                                     ref tokenHandle);            
        if (!returnValue)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
        impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
```

Impersonation seems to work. But I keep receiving an InvalidOperationException:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open MyService service on computer 'TargetMachine'. 
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
```

My Workstation is on a domain, while the target machine participates in a workgroup.

Any idea about what I am missing here?

Comment: Acces is denied. I had that when I didnt have admin rights.. Run VS in administrator mode. If it works then you just need to give your program admin right.

Comment: It works perfectly for local services. I also use  [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

Answer (score 0):

> My Workstation is on a domain, while the target machine participates in a workgroup

There is your problem. You are impersonating using a local or domain account. They are not part of the target machine since it's in a workgroup.

Comment: I am impersonating into a user which only exists on the workgroup machine. The Impersonation is successful and I also recieve some details regarding the service (Name and description), but nothing else is possible due to "access denied".